# LXC NAT forward host port to container

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, lxc, nat

I've installed LXC on a *debian/sid* and created a *jessie/amd64* container

```
sudo apt-get install lxc debootstrap libvirt-clients \
                libvirt-daemon-system ebtables dnsmasq

sudo lxc-create -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-debian -n debian
```

then I start the bridge

```
sudo virsh net-start default
```

This create 2 network if `virbr0` and `virbr0-nic`, `veth94ECU1` is created after `lxc-start`, is using the network `192.168.122.0/24` and the ip is assigned by dhcp.

The container start fine, it can reach the host and viceversa, I can ping it and if there's a web server running I can access with a browser from the host.

`virsh net-start` also add some rule to `iptables` (I don't have a firewall running on the host so by default everything is empty and `ACCEPT`)

`iptables -L` after `net-start`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
```

`iptables -L -t nat` after `net-start`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     base-address.mcast.net/24 
RETURN     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is `1`

Now I'd like to NAT some host port to the container, finding a solution everything online seems to point in the same direction, something like that below should work:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport $HPORT -j DNAT --to $VRIP:$VRPORT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $VRIP --dport $VRPORT -j ACCEPT
```

but it isn't, what I'm missing?

**update**

I switched from lxc-nat/virsh net-start (virbr0) to host nat (br0) following this post: [Converting eth0 to br0 and getting all your LXC or LXD onto your LAN](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2015/11/10/converting-eth0-to-br0-and-getting-all-your-lxc-or-lxd-onto-your-lan/index.html)

It works, containers get the ip via dhcp from the LAN router and are in the same net, that's convenient because my router can NAT-port forward only LAN addresses.

Briefly, create a `br0` interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`, like that:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.210
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    bridge-ifaces eth0
    bridge-ports eth0
    up ifconfig eth0 up

iface eth0 inet manual
```

then use `lxc.network.link = br0` in the container config.

Still, if somebody know a way to NAT only some port without using an host bridge I'd like to hear about.

Comment: Are you trying to port forward (so the outside world can hit the container) or NAT so the container can reach the outside world (but only on certain ports)?

Comment: @user1794469 I was trying to NAT from internet -> host -> lxc container (and it works with the bridge interface, I'm still using it). Recently I changed provider and it require to pay for a static ip to allow NAT, had to add something like ngrok

Answer (score 1):

If you use nfttables, you need to setup nat so the LXC can access the outside world.

```
table ip lxc {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.0.3.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.3.0/24 masquerade
    }
}
```

And to NAT inwards (from the Internet) , e.g. port 2222 on the Internet to port 22 on an lxc container use the *prerouting* chain in the *nat* table.

```
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp ip daddr $public_ip tcp dport 2222    dnat to $my_lxc_ip:22
    }
}
```